# How to show login page by default after logout?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I want to show my login screen after logout.

Currently without LogoutModule after logout my page is redirecting to a blank screen and if I implement it as per the documentation, it redirects to homepage.

Documentation reference: https://sap.github.io/spartacus/modules/LogoutModule.html

```
@NgModule({


imports: [
    PageLayoutModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: null,
        canActivate: [LogoutGuard, CmsPageGuard],
        component: PageLayoutComponent,
        data: { cxRoute: 'logout' },
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
```

I have tried protecting my homepage, however if I do that, I am unable to logout at all i.e. nothing is happening if I click logout.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by overriding the default `getRedirectUrl` from LogoutGuard.

Currently, the base class redirects to login page upon logout if and only if it's a closed shop. Meaning, the user must login before doing any action (early login).

An example of how to override the LogoutGuard behavior is to do the following:

1 - create your custom logout guard

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NewLogoutGuard extends LogoutGuard {
  constructor(
    auth: AuthService,
    cms: CmsService,
    semanticPathService: SemanticPathService,
    protectedRoutes: ProtectedRoutesService,
    router: Router,
    authRedirectService: AuthRedirectService
  ) {
    super(
      auth,
      cms,
      semanticPathService,
      protectedRoutes,
      router,
      authRedirectService
    );
  }

  protected getRedirectUrl(): UrlTree {
    return this.router.parseUrl(this.semanticPathService.get('login'));
  }
}
```

2 - aliasing the class providers by providing the new logout guard

```
    { provide: LogoutGuard, useExisting: NewLogoutGuard },
```